# Intentionally meaningless MIME type

Tags: html, mime-types

I have an object in a page that has neither data nor type so is invalid HTML5. The object is actually just a placeholder and gets replaced by Javascript depending on the browser and Flash support. I can't change the way that works or use an element other than object.

I want to provide a type purely for the purposes of validation. According to [RFC4735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4735) I can use example/something or video/example but the word example looks bad, like I've forgotten to replace it.

Can I safely use type="video/arbitraryunregisteredword" instead? I want all browsers to ignore it.

Edit: I've now discovered that Firefox will show a missing plugin prompt when anything unrecognised is specified for type. Is there any way round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not quite what you're looking for, but I'd pick a content type that the browser already knows how to deal with. e.g. `text/html` or `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 4288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.4) defines the `x-` prefix as not registerable. So you're fine with something like

```
video/x-this_is_a_dummy
```

Comment: Thanks for the good info. Unfortunately this fails the ignored by browsers test in Firefox, as I've now added to the question.

Comment: Have you tried `application/octetstream`? It's kind of the generic fallback for binary data, like `text/plain` suggested by Alohci.